# Use jQuery DOM selector syntax in PhantomJS?

Tags: jquery, phantomjs

I'm learning PhantomJS and wondered if it's possible to use jQuery DOM selectors in the JS files PhantomJS runs?  I've seen a short example on github that appears to indicate this:

[Sample of PhantomJS with Qunit (and jQuery?)](https://gist.github.com/1305062/)

If you look at the run-qunit.js file at the top it seems state you can use jQuery DOM selectors as parameters.  But I'm getting errors when I do that-- not sure whether it's my syntax or because Phantom doesn't know about jQuery, so I thought I'd ask first about the PhantomJS/jQuery relationship.

Comment: It shows that you can use jQuery methods that return a boolean value when executed, not selectors, unless i'm not looking in the same place you are. What have you tried that isn't working?

Answer (score 4):

Use  page.injectJs('jquery-1.6.1.min.js'); it will work fine.

here is a beautiful link for using jquery in phantomjs
*[http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/534-how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-phantomjs-and-jquery](http://web.archive.org/web/20150713103425/http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/534-how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-phantomjs-and-jquery)*

Comment: helpful link...sandip da

Comment: The linked example doesn't work properly. The function passed as the second parameter of page.open() needs to be assigned to page.onLoadFinished instead, otherwise its not called by the second page load.

Comment: See the archive at: http://web.archive.org/web/20150713103425/http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/534-how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-phantomjs-and-jquery

Answer (score 2):

There is people telling that documentation samples loading JQuery are buggy and load JQuery on PhamtomJS is impossible here: [loading jquery on phanthomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847123/on-phantomjs-cant-include-jquery-and-without-jquery-cant-post-form-data?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

..well, as soon as I posted, I (naturally) found this.  Looks like it is possible in fact to include jQuery:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Page-Automation