# PhantomJS .click() not working

Tags: javascript, click, phantomjs

This code does not work:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://www.ebay.com/', function() {
    console.log('Page loaded');
    page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
        console.log('jQuery included');
        page.render('C:/beforeclick.jpeg');
        console.log('Render 1');
        page.evaluate(function() {
            $('.btn-prim').click();
        });
        page.render('C:/afterclick.jpeg');
        console.log('Render 2');
    });
});
```

In fact $('.btn-prim').click() does not work, beforeclick.jpeg and afterclick.jpeg are the same. In browser console $('.btn-prim').click() works fine. Ebay here just for example, it does not work on other sites too. Please help me to solve the problem, I am novice in JavaScript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265604/use-jquery-dom-selector-syntax-in-phantomjs

Comment: nothing helpful, can you explain please?

Comment: have u tried install jquery by doing ``npm install jquery`` and then ``$ = require('jquery');`` in your code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will give you a proper solution to the situation

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    var a = document.getElementById("target_element_to_be_clicked");
    var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @ArtjomB. I just answered my sample since its more clear one.

Comment: Please also customize your answer to fit the OP. What is `#spr-sign-in-btn-standard`? You should incorporate `.btn-prim` (for example with `document.querySelector`).

Comment: That was it. Great solution.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
function click(el){
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    ev.initMouseEvent(
        "click",
        true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
        window, null,
        0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
        false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
        0 /*left*/, null
    );
    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```